# Memory management in objective c arrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory-management, retain, retaincount

For this question:

```
Test *t1 = [[Test alloc]init];
Test *t2 = [Test new];
Test *t3 = [t1 copy];

NSLog(@"Retain count of Object 1 : %ld",[t1 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"Retain count of Object 2 : %ld",[t2 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"Retain count of Object 3 : %ld",[t3 retainCount]);

NSArray *arr = @[t1,t2,t3];

NSLog(@"Retain count of Object 1 : %ld",[t1 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"Retain count of Object 2 : %ld",[t2 retainCount]);
NSLog(@"Retain count of Object 3 : %ld",[t3 retainCount]);
```

The answer is:

Retain count of Object 1 : 1
Retain count of Object 2 : 1
Retain count of Object 3 : 1
Retain count of Object 1 : 3
Retain count of Object 2 : 2
Retain count of Object 3 : 3

I can understand that adding an object to an array increases its reference count by 1, but for objects 1 & 3 it increases by 2??
Can someone answer this?

Comment: Ref [this](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: It is most definitely a bad idea to reference `retainCount` as there could be any number of things going on under the hood. Apple encourages you to think in terms of object graphs, not retain counts.

Comment: Yep I am a trainer and I need an explanation Why this is happening!!

Comment: It is impossible to know what `copy` does because it calls the `copyWithZone:` method of your object, which you have not shown (and without which the call would raise an exception).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have shown (which doesn't show how the class is implemented), here is a guess:

- Your `Test` class's `copyWithZone:` method returns the receiver object itself, without retaining. (Which by the way is a violation of the memory management rules, which says that a method starting with `copy` must return an owning (retained) instance. A class's `copy` is allowed to return the object itself or a new object, but in both cases it must retain it.)
- Therefore, `t1` and `t3` point to the same object, which only has 1 retain count, when the object was created. (Since the `copy` incorrectly didn't retain.)
- When you put elements into an array, the array retains each element. So the object pointed to by `t2` gets retained once, getting a retain count of 2, and the object pointed to by `t1` and `t3` gets retained twice, getting a retain count of 3.